# Trouble deploying Spring Batch Admin Sample app on Tomcat 9

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat9

I downloaded the latest Spring Batch Admin: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-admin

I used mvn to package/install the application and got a WAR file in /target directory named:L spring-batch-admin-sample-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war

I've installed Tomcat 9 locally. I create a server in Eclipse and deployed the project WAR into it.

When I try to access the app using http://localhost:8080/spring-batch-admin-sample I get a 404 Error in the browser.   I tried to follow all the instructions in the reference document [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/trunk/reference/reference.pdf), but still have no luck depoying the sample.

Can someone please drop me a hint.

Comment: I tried with mvn install - though maybe mvn package wasn't good enough.  I deployed spring-batch-admin-sample-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war from my /target dir after that.... but it doesn't recognize the context that the Reference guide says I should use:
```http://localhost:8080/spring-batch-admin-sample```

Comment: I was able to launch it by starting TC 'manually' outside of Eclipse and deploying the WAR through the Manager.  I then had to enter ```http://localhost:8080/spring-batch-admin-sample/home``` in the browser and voila, I got the list of urls.... why all this trouble?

Comment: Why doesn't this Forward work in the index.jsp - anybody else have that problem?